# Why does the amadeus flight delay service returns internal error?

Tags: amadeus

we sometimes get an internal error from Amadeus when calling this endpoint:

```
/v1/travel/predictions/flight-delay?<a bunch of parameters>
```

The error we get is:

```
500 Internal Server Error: [{"errors":[{"code":200,"detail":"Inference error. Data not seen at training time","status":501,"title":"INFERENCE ERROR"}]}]
```

Is this an error we should just ignore?

Thanks,
Bjørn Hjelle

Expected not to get status code 500 returned when calling the endpoint.

Comment: A bit of context could help. What is "sometimes"? 1 on 10 requests? 1 on 100? 1 on 1000? Could it be related to the unshown parameters?

Comment: Yes, I agree, I will need to add more logging on our side to find out. The current logs show that it happened 37 times on February 23, and 64 times the day before. But you are right, I will get those numbers.

Comment: @kebs Actually, by studying the logs:

22nd of February: 91 successful requests, 64 requests failed
, 23rd of February: 164 successful requests, 37 failed

Will add logging to see if I can see some patterns in the failed requests.

Comment: I will also add more logging to see if it is certain requests (parameters) that fail.

Comment: This has not happened the last few months, so I will assume it has been fixed on that Amadeus side.